# Python executable permissions on Windows

Tags: python, windows, permissions

I am developing python app for Windows 7. But I have problem with permissions. I created .exe file from my .py script with Pyinstaller.
When I run my app on admin account app works perfectly (read images from local disc and from USB).
But when I run the same app on account without admin privileges app crash during opening images from disc. But when I want to read images from USB app works ok.
The computer on which I run the .exe is not the same one on which the file was generated.
Anybody know how to add the permissions to the .exe manifesto? Or is there a way to run the application correctly without administrator privileges? This is important because the application saves data on the disk, which must then be able to read.
Best regards

Comment: By "crash", do you mean an abnormal termination due to an unhandled Windows exception or Unix signal, or do you mean it exits due to an unhandled Python exception? If it's the latter, then you simply lack permission to open the files. Check the security on the files to see who has access. In the command prompt you can show this via `icacls "path\to\file"`. The owner, administrators and SYSTEM commonly have access.

Comment: By "crash" I mean  unhandled Python exception. The application in the account with administrator rights can use gdcm. But in an account without administrator privileges, not. Can I change these settings somehow, for example in a manifest file?